# SpecFlow and Xamarin Studio Integration with Custom Templates

Tags: specflow, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-templates

I'm currently looking at using SpecFlow in conjunction with Xamarin Studio for writing BDD tests for cross-platform mobile apps.

I've been using the Xamarin Studio add-in developed here https://github.com/mikeyjones/SpecFlow to integrate SpecFlow into the IDE.

What I need to be able to do is add some extra steps into the process when a new feature file is created, namely to create a new file to hold additional code I need in the feature class.

So I would end up with,

NewFeature.feature

NewFeature.feature.cs (code-behind defining partial class)

NewFeature.cs (where I add additional code to the partial class)

I also need to be able to add some additional code to the template that creates the step definitions for the feature.

The above repo contains the code that is currently producing the new files but I'm struggling to understand how this works in order to figure out how to integrate with it to add my own additions.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Comment: Have you asked by raising an issue at the GitHub page?